# Odoo 10 - ParseError:

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

Odoo 10 - 
I am trying to create an attendance module for partners rather than employees. I am copying code from the Attendance Module included in Odoo but am stuck and getting ParseError. The problem seems to be the action="base.res_partner_kanban_view"/>

The error is below

> ParseError: "ir.actions.view" while parsing
>   /opt/odoo/odoo10/odoo-10.0/customaddons/gym_attendance/views/gym_attendance_view.xml:93,
>   near

```
<menuitem id="menu_gym_attendance_view_members_kanban" name="Members" parent="menu_gym_attendance_manage_attendances" sequence="15" action="base.res_partner_kanban_view
```

Below is my XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <!-- views -->

    <record id="view_attendance_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">gym.attendance.tree</field>
        <field name="model">gym.attendance</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Member attendances">
                <field name="partner_id"/>
                <field name="check_in"/>
                <field name="check_out"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="gym_attendance_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">gym.attendance.form</field>
        <field name="model">gym.attendance</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Member attendances">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="partner_id"/>
                        <field name="check_in"/>
                        <field name="check_out"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="gym_attendance_view_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">gym_attendance_view_filter</field>
        <field name="model">gym.attendance</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Gym Attendance Search">
                <field name="partner_id"/>
                <!-- <field name="department_id"/> -->
                <filter name="today" string="Today" domain="[('check_in', '&gt;=', datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)),('check_in', '&lt;=', datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59))]" />
                <filter string="Current Month" domain="[('check_in', '&gt;=', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-01'))]" />
                <separator/>
                <filter string="No Check Out" domain="[('check_out', '=', False)]" />
                <separator/>
                <filter string="My Attendances" domain="[('employee_id.user_id.id', '=', uid)]" />
                <group expand="0" string="Group By">
                    <filter name="member" string="Member" context="{'group_by':'partner_id'}"/>
                    <separator/>
                    <filter name="groupby_name" string="Month" context="{'group_by':'check_in'}"/>
                </group>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="gym_attendance_action_my_attendances" model="ir.actions.client">
        <field name="name">Attendance</field>
        <field name="tag">gym_attendance_my_attendances</field>
        <field name="target">main</field>
    </record>

    <!-- actions -->

    <record id="gym_attendance_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Attendances</field>
        <field name="res_model">gym.attendance</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_today":1}</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="gym_attendance_view_filter" />
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p>The attendance records of your members will be displayed here.</p>
            <p>Please make sure you're using the correct filter if you expected to see any.</p>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="gym_attendance_action_my_attendances" model="ir.actions.client">
        <field name="name">Gym Attendance</field>
        <field name="tag">gym_attendance_my_attendances</field>
        <field name="target">main</field>
    </record>



    <menuitem id="menu_gym_attendance_root" name="Attendances" sequence="90"  web_icon="gym_attendance,static/description/icon.png"/>

    <menuitem id="menu_gym_attendance_my_attendances" name="Gym Attendances" parent="menu_gym_attendance_root" sequence="10" action="gym_attendance_action_my_attendances"/>

    <menuitem id="menu_gym_attendance_manage_attendances" name="Manage Attendances" parent="menu_gym_attendance_root" sequence="20"/>

    <menuitem id="menu_gym_attendance_view_attendances" name="Attendances" parent="menu_gym_attendance_manage_attendances" sequence="10"  action="gym_attendance_action"/>

    <menuitem id="menu_gym_attendance_view_members_kanban" name="Members" parent="menu_gym_attendance_manage_attendances" sequence="15" action="base.res_partner_kanban_view"/>



</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you trying to call `id` of `kanban view` of `res.partner` instead of the id of action. Either you have to find out the correct `id` for the action or create a new one and use.

Here is the example id for Customer `base.action_partner_form` which available in `base/res/res_partner.xml`

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with : gym_attendance_action,

you need to specify the action to your menu-item and this action will call your view.

Your action:

```
<field name="search_view_id" ref="gym_attendance_view_filter" />
```

Your menu-item:

```
<menuitem id="id_menu_item" name="NameOfYourView" parent="model.model"
          action="turnover_filtered_view_action..." />
```